# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to invoke a procedure from another procedure?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How to invoke a procedure from another procedure in same adapter?

```
function getList(id){
var invocationData ={
adapter :'getDataAdapter',
procedure : 'getUser'
};

WL.Server.invokeProcedure( invocationData,function(){
onSuccess: function(){alert("success");},
onFailure: function(){alert("failure");}
}
}
```

I have written this code adapter js file.

Comment: Have you tried to invoke the second procedure on the onSuccess of the first procedure invocation with the results from it?

Comment: Yup.. I tried that but I need to call procedure from another procedure..

Comment: Why? What is the purpose? What do you expect/need to happen?

Comment: I wanted to do two way sms communication in all platforms. So the flow is sms will be send to sms gateway then gateway to worklight server and worklight server to backend system.. can u guide me to execute this flow

Comment: Well, did you read the training material about SMS?

Comment: From the question, I also can not tell what the actual problem is.  I've seen instances of WL.Server.invokeProcedure() being used to call an adapter procedure from another adapter procedure, and it does work.  What are you expecting to see happen in this code?  What is happening instead?  I note that you are indicating success or failure using alert(), and I don't think that's going to work - the adapter JavaScript code runs on the server, so there is nothing to display an alert() to.  Probably you should use one of the logging methods in WL.Logger instead?

Answer (score 0):

From the question and comments, it is not yet clear what exactly you need here...

Perhaps what you need is to separate your procedures to different adapters and then chain them? Read through the [Advanced adapter usage and mashup](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_07_Advanced_adapter_usage_and_mashup.pdf) training module and [sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AdapterMashUpProject.zip). Perhaps this is what you're looking for.

---

Based on more comments...

[2-way SMS communication training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_06_Two_way_SMS_communication.pdf)
[Sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/SMS2WayProject.zip)

Comment: Have read that pdf but I am not getting how to implement that methods and where

Comment: You have a sample project

Comment: I have gone through sample project. . But iit is not satisfying my requirement